# Can any DTS stream be embedded in a WAV as is?

Tags: surround-sound, wav, dts

I have some DTS files that I’d like to embed inside WAV to trick various devices into sending them to my receiver. I know this is possible, but details are hard to come by.

I have several examples of such files created by others. They all have these characteristics in common (output from the `mediainfo` command):

```
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Mode                                     : 14
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Codec ID                                 : 1
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 Kbps
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
```

The data that I want to embed looks like this:

```
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Mode                                     : 16
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Bit rate                                 : 754 Kbps
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
```

Is this possible, or does the data need to be manipulated before it can be embedded?

I've written a Python script that prepends a (probably incorrect) WAV header to the DTS data, but it just results in noise. The most obvious problem is that the duration of the WAV is calculated to be about half the actual duration. I assume this is because it's treating a 754 Kbps stream as 1411 Kbps.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? A quick web search makes it seem like the "DTS as .wav" trick is meant for burning DTS to a regular audio CD to be read by player that can interpret such CDs. See: http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/how_to_play_wav_dts_files.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Embedding a DTS stream within a WAV file is a clever hack, but a hack nevertheless, not guaranteed to work - only if the entire playback chain passes it through bit perfect will the receiver see a DTS stream. Otherwise you just have white noise.

You may wish to look at the following link.

http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Play_DVD_Tracks

Hope this helps. - S

Comment: I’m familiar with the challenges of playing back these files, and I’ve overcome them. My question is about *creating* them. Thanks for the link, though. It implies that 48 KHz should work.

Comment: That page has a section at the bottom about spdifconvert.py, which looks like it does what you want.